# Include static library via Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have three projects using the Android NDK. The first two build static libraries (one includes the other). I'm trying to include them as part of the build for the third but get various errors depending on how I set up my app in android studio 2.3.

I've read the other questions on this but they all refer to building the libraries as part of the same makefile. I need to be able to build the two as parts of different makes and reference the inner lib from relative paths.

Here's the most basic example I could create.

https://github.com/ginger-mcmurray/android.mk-inner-library-sample

Building the inner library works fine. Building the wrapper library also works, which I can tell by running nm on the .a files created.

```
PLNA007982-MBP:arm64-v8a ginger.mcmurray$ nm libInnerLibrary.a 

inner-library.o:
0000000000000000 n $d.1
0000000000000000 n $d.2
0000000000000000 n $d.3
0000000000000000 n $d.4
0000000000000000 n $d.5
0000000000000000 n $d.6
0000000000000000 r $d.7
0000000000000000 n $d.8
0000000000000000 t $x.0
0000000000000000 T innerLibraryMethod

PLNA007982-MBP:arm64-v8a ginger.mcmurray$ nm libWrapperLibrary.a 

wrapper-library.o:
0000000000000000 n $d.1
0000000000000000 n $d.2
0000000000000000 n $d.3
0000000000000000 n $d.4
0000000000000000 n $d.5
0000000000000000 n $d.6
0000000000000000 r $d.7
0000000000000000 n $d.8
0000000000000000 t $x.0
                 U innerLibraryMethod
0000000000000000 T wrapperLibraryMethod
```

I've followed the recommendations in all of the answers I can find on here and none of them work. The current version on github does not build. The error is

```
/Users/ginger.mcmurray/Jay-s-POC/ndk-test/hello-jni/app/src/main/cpp/src/hello-jni.c
Error:(34) undefined reference to 'wrapperLibraryMethod'
```

wrapperLibraryMethod is defined in libWrapperLibrary.a but not being found by the build.

Comment: Hi Ginger, what kind of error message are you getting? Those error messages may help us debug the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinK.Brown: Sorry, somehow it got chopped off of the original post. It's there now. (of course, by "somehow" I mean "user error.") :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have both **libWrapperLibrary.a** and **libInnererLibrary.a** built. You need copies of *both* libraries somewhere (e.g. in **jniLibs**). The following **CMakeLists.txt** picks the **inner-lib** from its *natural* location, and saves me the hassle of copying.

You must add both libraries separately, and specify them explicitly in `target_link_libraries`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( wrapper-lib
             STATIC
             IMPORTED )
add_library( inner-lib
             STATIC
             IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                       wrapper-lib

                       # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                       # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libWrapperLibrary.a )
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
                       inner-lib

                       # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
                       PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

                       # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../inner-library/obj/local/${ANDROID_ABI}/libInnerLibrary.a )

add_library(hello-jni SHARED
            src/hello-jni.c)

# Include libraries needed for hello-jni lib
target_link_libraries(hello-jni
                      wrapper-lib inner-lib
                      android
                      log)
```

---

1. The order of libraries in the `target_link_libraries` ***may matter***. To be on the safe side, I put **inner** after **wrapper**.
2. There is no easy way to import **inner-lib** objects into the **wrapper-lib**, but `ndk-build` allows to specify that using one static library (including a prebuilt one) requires also another one. This is irrelevant for your scenario, because there is no way to translate this information from *ndk-buildish* to *CMakeish*.
3. I understand that you prefer to use `ndk-build` to build them separately, just as an exercise, and in real life they will arrive prebuilt from an external source. But if you build at least the **wrapper-lib** yourself, it could save you a lot of headache if you use `ndk-build` also for the resulting shared library. Android Studio integrates with `ndk-build` not worse than with `CMake`, but it is insane to mix the two systems with gradle.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed. :)